# yum update impact on MariaDB

Tags: yum

Been using Linux not the first year, but it's the first I'm quite curious if yum update would not corrupt my setup. I'm running an Network Monitoring server - Observium on quite old Linux Centos release - 7.3.1611. Observium started to recommend to update MariaDB to 10 version, and Python to atleast 2.7.12.

I know by yum info that `yum update` would update MariaDb from 5.5.56 to 5.5.68. And that ok, later i would do it manually by recommendations from the internet.

But firstly i think it's quite good idea to update whole system with `yum update`, and later update everything that would be left manually. But i dont know - do the `yum update` would update MariaDb Db from 5.5.56 to 5.5.68 somehow gracefully or i need to take some extra protection steps ? Thank you

Comment: Did you check the release notes?  Anyhow, MariaDB will at least need to restart to use the new version.  You wouldn't expect the database needs changes for that level of upgrade.  You're aware that you'll need to replace CentOS soon?

Comment: You haven't installed updates in years! Do that yesterday. And never again let it go that long. MariaDB will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for assurance, will do it after holidays. I think i will be fine with the latest Centos 7.x release. Till we know what to do next to migrate to Debian or to Rocky Linux.